# Visual Studio 2010 Remove unneeded lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker

here's a simplified scenario of what I did:

1. A Visual Studio 2010 solution containing project (lib) A and B
2. I removed lib B, make adjustment, so A doesn't link to B in the code, now build.
3. I start to get errors, like:

   - Microsoft.Common.Targets(1200,9): warning : The referenced project B.vcxproj does not exist
   - LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file: 'path-to-\B.lib'

Peeking Configuration Properties->Linker->Command Line, I can see B.lib is hanging around there no matter what I do. I believe this is some VS project setting bug, anybody has similar experience and know some workaround?

I'm aware that recreating my project A, pulling in all the files may solve this, but just encounter this too many times. Hope to throw it here, and if there is good answer, also benefit the community a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Project + Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References.  If you still see B listed under References then remove it.

Comment: I'm assuming you have first cleaned the project rather than just attempting to build?

Comment: Thanks. The project is cleaned, and also in the Framework and Reference portion, B is not listed any more, so there is nothing to remove. However if check command line, B is still there. Feel this is a bug of VS, but surprised to see so little others asking about this

Comment: Got it solved: I think my case is a little bit special: I delete one porject, and replace it with a project with the same name but different path. Somehow VC got confused and still recognizing the old path. Have to remove the project, save solution, close , then re-open, clean project, make sure all dependencies are cleared, then start adding the new one back in. Hope this tip will be useful for others at some point. Thanks.